# Audio from Lightning dock?

Tags: iphone, audio, dock, lightning

Is Apple the only company that makes an iPhone dock with an audio out jack (3.5mm) that gets the audio straight from the Lightning port... as opposed to a separate audio plug? See example below:

[image]

I'm looking for something that won't bend my cable as I intend to thread it and undo it several times.

Comment: @bmike Thanks... but doesn't this edit make it _more_ about hardware shopping now? My original question was less "what thing should I buy" and more "how come Apple's thing can do something that third party things can't." As mentioned, Apple's dock gets the audio straight from the Lightning port. I haven't seen other docks that do that... so the question really is, can they?

Comment: I also steered it away from "Why does Apple do X - which also is off topic" - can they is a problematic "ask" for software and engineering. It's all a matter of money, time and constraints. We're here for practical questions that can have answers that objectively are right or wrong. Yes/no type questions are better suited elsewhere... Hit us up on [meta] if you get lost in the weeds on all the "guidance" - comments are too short to convey several posts in [help].

Answer (score 1):

I can only find one other manufacturer, but I guess that's sufficient to say Apple are **not** the only company to make a dock with audio out from the Lightning port.

[Henge Docks Gravitas](http://eu.hengedocks.com/pages/gravitas) can do this.

It's not completely clear from the web page that there is no separate audio plug going into the phone, but the [user guide](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.freshdesk.com/data/helpdesk/attachments/production/1030040802/original/Gravitas%20Lightning%20User%20Guide.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ2JSYZ7O3I4JO6DA&Expires=1450084223&Signature=N8Jrb4N722g5baFdvn%2BpNKlrHJ8%3D&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf) is clearer.
This structure enables you to have the phone connected to both computer/charger & external speakers, simultaneously.

[image]